# Golf - Expand Templates In Text File

Tags: code-golf

Golf - implement a simple templating scheme.

Expansions are:

- %KEY% -> VALUE
- %% -> %

Command line arguments:

- ARG1: dictionary file, formatted in the `key=value` style as in example
- ARG2: template file

Here my not quite golf attempt(python): 261 chars.

```
import sys
dd = dict([ll.split("=",2) for ll in open( sys.argv[1],'r') if len(ll.split("=", 2)) == 2])
tt = "".join([ ll for ll in open( sys.argv[2],'r')])
sys.stdout.write("".join([(((s == "") and "%") or ((s in dd) and dd[s]) or s) for s in tt.split("%")]))
```

DICT

```
NAME=MyName
ODDS=100
```

TEMPLATE

```
I, %NAME% am %ODDS% %% sure that that this a waste of time.
```

RESULT

```
I, My Name am 100 % sure that this is a waste of time.
```

Yes, I realize this is a defective templating system, "snaps" for a shorter and better implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you could leverage the inbuilt string formatting to make it shorter. Just needs a little regex hacking to get the syntax to match.

```
import sys, re
sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'%(.+?)%',r'%(\1)s',open(sys.argv[2]).read())%dict(l.split("=",2) for l in open(sys.argv[1],'r')))
```

Down to 139 bytes. (Though perhaps the args/file-IO stuff shouldn't really be part of a golf challenge?)

Answer (score 1):

C#.

```
string s = "NAME=MyName ODDS=100"; // any whitespace separates entries
string t = "I, %NAME% am %ODDS% %% sure that that this a waste of time.";

foreach(var p in s.Split().Select(l=>l.Split('=')).ToDictionary(
e=>"%"+e[0]+"%",e=>e[1]))t=t.Replace(p.Key,p.Value);t=t.Replace("%%","%");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

That's 159 for the algorithm portion, I believe.  Note that this may produce unexpected results if you feed it something like "NAME=%%" (it'll collapse the %% further into %) but any short simple algorithm will exhibit behavior like this one way or the other, since you have to do the string replacements in some order.

Answer (score 1):

in vc++.. might be the fastest way :)

```
void customFormat(const char* format, char dicItemSep, char dicValueSep, const char* dic, char* out)
{
    if(out)
    {
        const char x = '%';
        while(*format)
        {
            while(*format && *format != x)*out++=*format++;
        if(!*format || !*(++format))goto exit;
            if(*format == x)
            {
                *out++=x;
                continue;
            }
            const char *first = format;
            const char *d = dic;
            while(*first)
            {
                while(*d)
                {
                    while(*d && (*d != *first))d++;
                    if(*d == *first)
                    {
                        while((*first++ == *d++) && (*d != dicValueSep));
                        if(!*first)goto exit;
                        if(*d != dicValueSep || *first != x)
                        {
                            first = format;
                            while(*d && (*d != dicItemSep))d++;
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!*d)break;
                d++;
                while((*d != dicItemSep) && *d && (*out++ = *d++));
                format = ++first;
                break;
            }
        }
    exit:
        *out = 0;
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char t[1024];
    customFormat
        (
            "%NAME% am %ODDS% %% sure that that this a waste of time.",
            '\n',
            '=',
            "NAME=MyName\nODDS=100",
            t
        );
    printf("%s", t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby, 114 characters

```
d=Hash[*[open(ARGV[0]).read.scan(/(.+)=(.*)/),'','%'].flatten]
print open(ARGV[1]).read.gsub(/%([^%]*)%/){d[$1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the question, but I hope you realize that if you need this for any kind of real-word task, Python has a *much more readable* template format with `{variable}`

```
 # MyDict.py
 dict = {
     some : 'every',
     p : '?', 
     q : '?..'
 }

 # main file
 import MyDict
 print """
    What is {some}thing{p} 
    Who values this mysterious {some}thing{q}
 """.format(**dict)
```

If you want, you can preserve your dictionary format:

```
  with open(dictionary_file, 'r') as f:
      for l in f.readlines():
           k, v = '='.split(l)
           if v: dict[k] = v
```